# Function not defined in ejs

Tags: javascript, express

The function is not defined, I want to get the jobtitle and show it in the ejs file without the hyphen and capitalize the first letter
When i remove the function the job title is shown
I tried to change the received jobtitle in the route
example - (software-engineer) to (Software Engineer)

```js
router.get('/job/:jobTitle',(req,res) => {
  const { jobTitle } = req.params;
  res.render('job',{ jobTitle });
});
```

```html
<p class="job-title"><%= formatJobTitle(jobTitle) %></p>
    <script>
        function formatJobTitle(jobTitle) {
            const words = jobTitle.split('-');
            
            const formattedTitle = words.map(word => {
                return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
            }).join(' ');

            return formattedTitle;
        }
    </script>
```

```js
router.get('/job/:jobTitle', (req, res) => {
  const { jobTitle } = req.params;
  const formattedJobTitle = formatJobTitle(jobTitle);

  res.render('job', { jobTitle: formattedJobTitle });
});

function formatJobTitle(jobTitle) {
  const words = jobTitle.split('-');
  const formattedTitle = words.map(word => {
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }).join(' ');

  return formattedTitle;
}
```